# how to change CSP frame-ancestors in Figma plugin iFrame

Tags: iframe, plugins, figma

I have a figma plugin SPA written in react.
In the documentation of [oauth with figma](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/oauth-with-plugins) I'm supposed to:

> The plugin opens an iframe using the figma.showUI(...) API call. The iframe is necessary for accessing browser APIs for making network requests.
>
> This plugin iframe redirects to a hostname under your control, for example a page hosted on your internet server. This will place the iframe on a non-null origin, which enables us to securely check its identity later in the flow.

However when trying to redirect to my hostname using document.location.replace('https://myHostname.com/login'); I get the error message

> Refused to frame 'https://myHostname.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

I can't find in the documentation where can I change this CSP to make it work.